# UIWebView: How to tell when part of the HTML is visible?

Tags: uiwebview, scroll, uiwebviewdelegate

Is there a callback offered by UIWebView that is called when scrolling occurs, and if so, how can I get the current content offset?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can using this property available in ios 5.0:

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) UIScrollView *scrollView
```

Or prior to iOS 5.0:

```
NSArray *subViews = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[myWebview subviews]];
UIScrollView *webScroller = (UIScrollView *)[subViews objectAtIndex:0];
```

You can then implement the `UIScrollViewProtocol` and do something like this:

```
UIScrollView *webScrollView = myWebView.scrollView;
webScrollView.delegate = self;

//implement method from delegate..

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    //Scrolled
}
```

To get the contentOffset all you have to do is:

```
CGPoint offSet = webScrollView.contentOffset;
```

Comment: Wait, are you serious? With UIScrollView I've used scrollViewDidScroll. Why would that not work in iOS 4.x?

Comment: @Mithras What is new is the property in UIWebView :). See my updated answer on how to get a reference to the scrollView before 5.0.

Comment: Yep, that's what I was planning to do. Thanks.